# Install image magick 7 for php on ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

The current version of php-imagick uses Image Magick v6.x but I need to use v7. I have managed to do a build/make of the latest version which works on the command line but how can I get it working with php?

Comment: What PHP version are you using ?

Comment: 7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Comment: have you tried just 'pecl install imagick' ?